# Method for accessing S3 bucket with R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have latest R (3.3.1) and RStudio (0.99.902) installed. I get this error when trying to install 'Rawscli':

> package ‘Rawscli’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)

All the links I have found on accessing S3 bucket with R either deprecated or not willing to install the package.

With 'Gastrograph/RS3', it seems it doesn't give function to read file.
No success with 'aws.s3' either. I haven't found a fast tool to execute CLI within R.

I simply want to be able to read csv file in S3 bucket from RStudio Server on EC2.

Comment: Did you check this https://www.gastrograph.com/blogs/dev/using-s3-in-r.html

Comment: @error2007s yes I tried it and the package install didn't succeed. That's what I get 'Makevars.win:11: *** missing separator.  Stop.
Warning: l'exécution de la commande 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="RS3.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="RcppExports.o s3.o"' renvoie un statut 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RS3'
* removing 'D:/noblabla/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RS3'
Error: Command failed (1)'

Comment: This topic talks about the problem with 'Gastrograph/RS3' https://disqus.com/home/discussion/gastrograph/using_s3_buckets_in_r_with_rs3_library/

Comment: You can give [aws.s3](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) a try.